# having problem in mapping my geojson data on html page using Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, django-templates

how can I show my shape files- polygons on my website? I want to show my polygons on map but I cannot find the way. what should I do?
Could you Please help me?
Thanks
These are my codes :

my polygons/view.py( I want to show the "master_plan_dataset" on map):

```html
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.core import serializers
from .models import master_plan
from djgeojson.views import GeoJSONLayerView

class HomepageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index1.html"

def master_plan_dataset(request):
    master_plans = serializers.serialize('geojson', master_plan.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'layers.html', {'master_plans': master_plans})
```

my polygons/urls.py:

```html
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from djgeojson import views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomepageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^master_plan_dataset/$', views.master_plan_dataset, name='master_plan')
]
```

my polygons/models.py:

```html
class master_plan(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Landuse = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Shape_Area = models.FloatField(null=False)
    Name_per = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name_per
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Name_per

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'master_plan'
```

and also my Html template => layers.html:

### ```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{%load static%}
{%load leaflet_tags%}
<head>
    {%leaflet_js%}
    {%leaflet_css%}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>homepage</title>
    
    <style type="text/css">
        #gis {width:80%;height:500px;}
       
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dist/leaflet.ajax.js' %}">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
<h3>
    THE WEB SPATIAL DATABASE
</h3>
<br>
<div>
<script type = "text/javascript">

     function display_layers(map, options)
     {
         var dataset = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'master_plan' %}", {

           });
           dataset.addTo(map);
     }

    </script>
</div>
{% leaflet_map "gis" callback="window.display_layers" %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear. Is your problem on the server side or client side?

Comment: Actually I'm a beginner I  don't know exactly but I think it's on client side